# the use of strcpy in C

Tags: c, strcpy

okay, so basically ive been writing a program in the form of a tournament out of 16 players. I'm currently writing the code for the first round using loops and then attempting to send the winners of each match to a new array called R2CONTESTANTS. However, when i print all those inside the R2CONTESTANTS array, it stores only half the strings and half random characters every other element of the array ([1],[3]. Any help would be appreciated, been stuck for hours.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CONTESTANTS 16
#define R2CONTESTANTS 8
#define MATCHNO 8

//Forward Declarations
int R1(char Name [][20]);

int main(void)
{
  GetNames();
  int R1(char Name[][20]);
  return 0;
}

int GetNames(void)
{
  char Name[CONTESTANTS][20];
  int n;


  printf("Hello and Welcome to the 2014 Tennis Knockout Competition!\n");
  printf("Please enter the names of all 16 players (MAX 20 CHARACTERS): \n");

/*Get Names loop*/
  for(n = 0; n < CONTESTANTS ; n++)
    {
      printf("%d >>", n+1);
      scanf("%20s", Name[n]);
      fflush(stdin); 
    }
  R1(Name);
}

int R1(char Name[][20])
{
  int m/*match counter*/, i=0/*PLAYER COUNT*/, n/*TEST*/ ;
  int WinNO;
  char R2Name[R2CONTESTANTS][20];

  printf("Welcome to Round 1!\n");

  for( m = 0 ; m < MATCHNO ; m++, i+=2 ) //PER MATCH
    {
      printf("\nMatch %d of %d.\n", m+1, MATCHNO);
      printf("\n1.   %s   v   2.   %s\n", Name[i], Name[i+1]);
      printf("\nPlease enter number of winner: ");
      scanf("%d", &WinNO);
       /*WINNER/LOSER*/
      switch(WinNO)//STRCPY is sending too many elements to R2CONTESTANTS array.
        {
          case 1:
          strcpy(R2Name[i], Name[i]);
          //printf("%s is sent through to the next round.\n", Name[i]);
          break;
          case 2:
          strcpy(R2Name[i], Name[i+1]);
          //printf("%s is sent through to the next round.\n", Name[i+1]);
          break;
          default: 
          printf("something went wrong\n"); //IMPROVE
          break;
      }


     }
  //TEST
  for(n = 0 ; n < R2CONTESTANTS ; n++)
  {
      printf("Winner %d: %s\n", n+1, R2Name[n]);
  }
}
```

This is whats now inside R2CONTESTANTS:

Winner 1: a
Winner 2: �
Winner 3: c
Winner 4: 
Winner 5: e
Winner 6: �
Winner 7: g
Winner 8:   �

Comment: Try compiling with full warnings `-Wall -Werror -pedantic` and you'll find some errors.

Comment: `strcpy(R2Name[X], Name[Y]);` X and Y must be managed separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're copying into R2Name[i] but i is incremented by 2 every iteration, so only R2Name[0], R2Name[2] etc get filled out. m increments by only 1 each time, so you could instead copy to R2Name[m] which should solve the problem.